# Issue while creating a class using YeoMan

Tags: asp.net, yeoman, yeoman-generator

I'm trying to create a code generator for the class library using `YeoMan`.

Here what I have tried is as mentioned below:

```
E:\Learnings\YeoMan Code Generator>mkdir YeoManClassLibrary

E:\Learnings\YeoMan Code Generator>cd YeoManClassLibrary

E:\Learnings\YeoMan Code Generator\YeoManClassLibrary>yo generator-aspnet
Installed generators don't need the "generator-" prefix.
In the future, run yo aspnet instead!


     _-----_     ╭──────────────────────────╮
    |       |    │      Welcome to the      │
    |--(o)--|    │  marvellous ASP.NET Core │
   `---------´   │        generator!        │
    ( _´U`_ )    ╰──────────────────────────╯
    /___A___\   /
     |  ~  |
   __'.___.'__
 ´   `  |° ´ Y `

? What type of application do you want to create? Class Library
? What's the name of your ASP.NET application? MyClassLibrary
   create MyClassLibrary\.gitignore
   create MyClassLibrary\Class1.cs
   create MyClassLibrary\MyClassLibrary.csproj
   create MyClassLibrary\global.json


Your project is now created, you can use the following commands to get going
    cd "MyClassLibrary"
    dotnet restore
    dotnet build (optional, build will also happen when it's run)



E:\Learnings\YeoMan Code Generator\YeoManClassLibrary>cd MyClassLibrary
E:\Learnings\YeoMan Code Generator\YeoManClassLibrary\MyClassLibrary>dotnet restore
  Restoring packages for E:\Learnings\YeoMan Code Generator\YeoManClassLibrary\MyClassLibrary\MyClassLibrary.csproj...
  Generating MSBuild file E:\Learnings\YeoMan Code Generator\YeoManClassLibrary\MyClassLibrary\obj\MyClassLibrary.csproj.nuget.g.props.
  Generating MSBuild file E:\Learnings\YeoMan Code Generator\YeoManClassLibrary\MyClassLibrary\obj\MyClassLibrary.csproj.nuget.g.targets.
  Restore completed in 14.57 sec for E:\Learnings\YeoMan Code Generator\YeoManClassLibrary\MyClassLibrary\MyClassLibrary.csproj.
```

Till here, everything is working fine.

But when I try to create a class from [this reference](https://medium.com/@RobertKhou/how-install-and-use-yeoman-to-generate-a-asp-net-core-app-95490615fb94), it is throwing an error as below:

```
E:\Learnings\YeoMan Code Generator\YeoManClassLibrary\MyClassLibrary>yo aspnet:class Customer
Error aspnet:class Customer

You don't seem to have a generator with the name “aspnet:class” installed.
But help is on the way:

You can see available generators via npm search yeoman-generator or via http://yeoman.io/generators/.
Install them with npm install generator-aspnet:class.

To see all your installed generators run yo without any arguments. Adding the --help option will also show subgenerators.

If yo cannot find the generator, run yo doctor to troubleshoot your system.
```

Also, I'm looking for a reference that how can I create custom templates for  **.Net** using **YeoMan**.